# Plotly R event zoom in and zoom out

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, plotly, bar-chart

I m trying to create dynamic plots in plotly R. The idea is that I have a bar plot with plotly.. Each bar is calculated behind the hood by a bunch of variables.. Typically a linear combination of them...

WHAT I WANT

I want the folowing: when i zoom in (or click) on a bar in my bar plot the graph is automatically changing to another graph which details the bar I clicked on.. And when I zoom out I retreive the first barplot graph.

Its like embedded graphes triggred by zoom in and zoom out events.

Anyone to help please ?? Thanks a lot

Comment: What have you tried and failed so far ? It will be easier for people to offer help if some relevent code snippet is present too.

Comment: Thanks for replying. So far i didnt tried anything because I have no idea about how to proceed. I know that plotly supports events.. The idea I have is that I will trigger the event and rerender the plot anytime I zoom out. Will come. Black with snippet